# (VHDL) I'm Receiving an Error When Trying to Output from an Array

Tags: arrays, output, vhdl, seven-segment-display

I'm trying to output data inside an array to the 7-segment display on my DE1-SoC board.

Here are my variables:

`display : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);`

`type bigDisplay is array (0 to 4, 0 to 6) of bit;`

`signal displayArray : bigDisplay;`

Here is the code:

`display <= displayArray (0, 6-0);`

This is the error I receive:

`Error (10381): VHDL Type Mismatch error at Final_Project.vhd(326): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_logic_vector", the type of the target expression`

So, I'm guessing I need to convert my bit array to output to the std_logic_vector? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason for using `bit`? You can just as easily create an array of `std_logic_vector`:

```
type bigDisplay is array(0 to 4) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
signal displayArray : bigDisplay;
```

Then simply (after initializing `displayArray` with values, of course):

```
display <= displayArray(0);
```

Etc, or whatever index you desire, in order to assign values from your array to the display.

Comment: Hmm okay. I was using that type of array to hold 5 different sets of 7 bit values to send to my display. (So I could reference it like: displayArray (0, 6-0), displayArray (1, 6-0), displayArray (2, 6-0) etc.) Can I treat std_logic_vectors the same way?

Comment: When I tried it like this: 
`type bigDisplay is array (0 to 4) of std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);` 
`display <= displayArray (0, 6-0);`

I got the error: 
`index of object of array type bigDisplay must have 1 dimensions`

Comment: You need to remove the `, 6-0` part, as now your array is of `std_logic_vector`, rather than a 2-d array of `bit`.

Comment: Okay. I guess the solution would be to create 5 different logic vectors, each holding 7 values. Thanks. :)

Comment: Once you have your `array` of `std_logic_vector`, you can initialize them like this `displayArray <= ("0000101","0000000","0011001","1111111","1010101");`, and index them like `displayArray(0) <= ... displayArray(1) <= ...`, rather than creating 5 separate logic vectors.